# Can not print out gameobject's position's value correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, 2d

When trying to print out (debug) my objects value, it gives me the position's value of where it's original position is (the startposition in world space). So my object is placed in -3.51 in y in world space before starting the game, therefore it only prints out -3,51 on every update despite the fact that in the inspector you can see the y position (in transform) changing when the object moves.

This is the code that does it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// Icke procedurell

public class createLevels : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject doodle;
    public Transform doodleTransform;

    public GameObject greenPlatform;

    public float distMultiplier = 1f;

    public float valueY;
    public int ammountPlatforms = 10;
    public float levelWidth = 3f;
    public float minY = 0.2f;
    public float maxY = 1.5f;
    public Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3();


    void Start()
    {


        for (int i = 0;i < ammountPlatforms; i++) // Instansierar en startsumma platformar.
        {
            spawnPosition.y += Random.Range(minY, maxY); // Ökning i y
            spawnPosition.x = Random.Range(-levelWidth, levelWidth); // Ingen ökning i x..
            Instantiate(greenPlatform, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }   
    }

    void Update()
    {
       Debug.Log(doodle.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y);

    /*
        if (doodleTransform.position.y >= 10)
    {
            Debug.Log("I am over a certain distance.");
            distMultiplier++;
            Instantiate(greenPlatform, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);

    }
    */
    }

}
```

Also note that this is a script on another gameobject referencing my "wanted" gameobject's position.

To summarize the question, if you look in the update function, observe the "Debug.Log". It only prints out my startvalue, and i am trying to print out the objects position in y in realtime, being dynamic.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but can't you just use `doodle.transform` instead of `doodle.GetComponent<Transform>()`?

Comment: is the object perhaps a child of anything in the scene ?

Comment: @Shogunivar Wow i feel stupid. You said you didn't answer my question, but you did! I guess, when writing the way i did (with getting the component) i assume it takes the values once and prints that, like the component's state when the game hasn't started maybe. I assumed you'd have to write `doodle.GetComponent<Transform>().position.y` because it is a component, and there was "no" other way of reaching it.. But i was wrong, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Slypez ah alright cool, glad it helped

Comment: Your code is messed up on so many levels. No offence :) Why do you have doodle and doodleTransform one object can be used for both properties. Wait a minute! why do you even need doodle object in this class, just for debugging? do it in doodle's own script. And keep the code clean

Comment: I only have the "doodle" variable now, cause i didnt realise i could call a "Transform" type, from a "gameobject" type (which it is). Im not also sure what you mean by: "Your code is messed up on so many levels." since the only mistake was that i had 2 variables instead of 1. I need the doodle position in this class because i'm going to generate platforms relative to its position. So again, don't assume "do it in doodle's own script" if it wasn't my question. And lastly "And keep the code clean" is a bit fuzzy for me. Could you elaborate? I only see that it was unneeded with "doodleTransform".

Comment: Firstly, this class is responsible for instantiating platforms. And creating platforms based on player's position is a bad idea. What if the player keeps jumping on the same platform and never goes up on next (higher) one. You would end up creating so many platforms at the undesired position. Secondly, `if (doodleTransform.position.y >= 10)` would be true for every frame (60 times a second for 60 fps) that means it will instantiate a platform every frame when your player is above 10. Thirdly, `spawnPosition` is never updated before creating new platform.

Comment: 1st point: First of all you bring up something irrelevant compared to my question, and i didn't need help with this. And you misunderstand the way im gonna generate platforms but ok.. You're thinking the opposite solution. Im going to instantiate platforms relative to his position, meaning i wont get what you are talking about. for ex. I might instantiate 15 platforms when he has reached the value of 10 in Y. I will ofc make an if statement that mulitplies with everytime it has executed, so therefore an example would be 30 platforms at 20 (in Y), and 60 at 40 (in Y) etc.

Comment: 2st point: You bring up things i am experimenting with, which i also am not mentioning in the question. Understand that i am still learning, and if you look at the earlier comments, i solved the problem from @Shogunivar's solution. So why would you bring up faulty code, that i know is faulty, because he has already solved it. You bring up the bad in my if statement, and the variable "spawnPosition". But i have not asked for any advise on that. And understand that i am just "debugging" and such, and i am not trying to finalize a script here.. I just wanted to generate platforms in my game fast.

Comment: Addressing the thing that Shogunivar said: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html GameObjects always have a reference to their transform (and all components have a reference to their GameObject) available as a public property. They literally can't exist without them (i.e. a game object *requires* a transform component and components are *required* to be attached to game objects).